# How to send email using mail composer plugin in iphone using phone gap jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, mfmailcomposer

I have implemented an app using **jQuery Mobile in PhoneGap (corDova).**

I have down loded the **EmailComposer plugin** for sending email.

I added EmailCompser.js in my www folder and EmailCompser.h, EmailCompser.m in resource folder of application.

I have created a button in jQuery mobile.

Now i want to **populate mail composer view when click on the Mail button**

```
<a href="???" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left" >E-MAIL</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not open on click of a link unless you write the cordova code to initiate the plugin, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openMail(){
  var args;
  Cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="openMail()" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left" >E-MAIL</a>
```

Comment: How to attach a file to the mail in iPhone PhoneGap jQuery Mobile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341503/how-to-attach-a-file-to-the-mail-in-iphone-phonegap-jquery-mobile

Comment: file attachment is not supported yet, however if you want to attach a static file then there is a commented code in the `EmailComposer.m` which you can check.

Comment: Have you tried this with version 1.9 of phoneGap? -I am having trouble getting it to compile