# How to attach a file to the mail in iPhone PhoneGap jQuery Mobile 

Tags: javascript, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I Have implemented an **iPhone application in Phone Gap using jQuery Mobile.**

As the part of my app i need to **send an email by click on a Button 'MAIL'**

For that i added  **`EmailComposer plug in.`**

added  EmailComposer.js in www folder and

added  EmailComposer.H and .M file in Resources folder of application.

I implemented the code as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="EmailComposer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

      function SendEmail() { 

           alert('XXXXX');

        window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("SubjectXXX","PlainTextBody---", 
                                 "recipientName,recipientName", "ccRecipient", "bccRecipient",false); 
        } 
  </script> 



<a href="#" onclick="SendEmail(); return false;"  data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left" >Send</a>
```

Mail composer view displays all is well.

**Now I need to Atach a file to this email how to attach a file**

Can any one guide me the way

tahnks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I have been trying to open mailcomposer in iOS but unable to do it can you please give me your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
var attachPath; 
                var attachFile= new Array();
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("MyAppFolder", {
                        create: true
                    }, 
        function(directory) {
            console.log("Final 63" + directory.fullPath);
            attachPaths = directory.fullPath;
            var attachPath=attachPaths.slice(7,attachPaths.length);
            var directoryReader = directory.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    console.log(entries[i].name);
attachFile[i] =attachPath + "/" + entries[i].name;
                            }
                            console.log(attachFile);
                        }, 
                        function (error) {
                            alert(error.code);
                        });

                    });
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("can't even get the file system: " + error.code);
                });
```

Now pass attachFile to mailcomposer

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(null,
                    "Get an Estimate",
                     "Body",
                ["mail_id"],
                    [],
                    [],
                    true,
                    attachFile
                    );
```

Hope this helps you!!!!!